# SQL Query Removing extra line CHAR(10) in string

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm having a hard time to formulate replace for strings with line space or char (10)

test string

```
"1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)"
```

expected result

```
1st line string 
2nd line string 
3rd line string
```

how to achieve this output?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?  Your expected result is unclear.  Which characters constitute a new line in your file?

Comment: into MSSQL, you can 
select '1st line string'+char(10)+'2nd line string' + char(10)+ '3rd line string'

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPLIT_STR function

like this

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)", 'char(10)', 1)  ,
       SPLIT_STR("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)", 'char(10) ', 3) ,
SPLIT_STR("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)", 'char(10) ', 5)
```

Comment: thank you but it will generate  "1st line string 2nd line string 3rd line string"   my expected output would be  "1st line string char(10) 2nd line string char(10) 3rd line string char(10).

Comment: @iCeR That's not the same expected output you wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `REPLACE` function to replace `char(10)` with a newline character.

```
REPLACE("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)", "char(10)", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like nearly what you looking for:
you must change the String to you DB field

```
SELECT
TRIM(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE( 
      REPLACE("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)",
             ' char(10) char(10) char(10) ',
             '\n'),
         ' char(10) char(10) ',
         '\n'),
       ' char(10)',
       '\n')
     );
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT
    -> TRIM(
    ->   REPLACE(
    ->     REPLACE(
    ->       REPLACE("1st line string  char(10) char(10) 2nd line string  char(10) char(10) char(10) 3rd line string  char(10)",
    ->              ' char(10) char(10) char(10) ',
    ->              '\n'),
    ->          ' char(10) char(10) ',
    ->          '\n'),
    ->        ' char(10)',
    ->        '\n')
    ->      ) AS result;
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| result                                              |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1st line string
2nd line string
3rd line string
 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys, I came up with this. I will translate it to function

```
   DECLARE @str  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @str = 'TEST ' + CHAR(10)  + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10) + 'TEST ' + CHAR(10)+ CHAR(10)+ CHAR(10)+ CHAR(10)+ 'TEST ' + CHAR(10)+'TEST ' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10)+ CHAR(10);

    SELECT @str  = REPLACE(@str,CHAR(10),'{}')

    WHILE (CHARINDEX('}{',CONVERT (VARCHAR(MAX),@str),0) >0 )
         SELECT @str  = REPLACE(@str,'}{','')



    SELECT REPLACE(@str,'{}',CHAR(10))
```